# Создание диалогового окна

Tags: c++, qt

Не до конца понимаю, как создать диалоговое окно с несколькими `LineEdit`'ами, а затем по нажатию кнопки OK, получить с них значения. Если можно пример какой-нибудь?
Класс диалога реализую так:

```
#ifndef DIAL_H
#define DIAL_H

#include <QDialog>

class dial : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit dial(QWidget *parent = 0);
    int s;
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // DIAL_H
```

cpp

```
    #include "dial.h"

dial::dial(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent)
{
}

void dial::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
     //s = ui->lineEdit->text().toInt(); // сохраняем результат
     accept(); // говорим что диалог выполнился успешно (а не закрыт с отменой)
}
```

Окно появляется но на нём нет никаких элементов как добавить их? а потом по слику на кнопку считать данные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Виджеты в Qt построены таким образом, что в подавляющем большинстве случаев нет никакой необходимости наследовать базовые классы. Особенно это касается `QDialog`.

```
QDialog dlg(this);
dlg.setWindowTitle(tr("My dialog"));

QLineEdit *ledit1 = new QLineEdit(&dlg);
QLineEdit *ledit2 = new QLineEdit(&dlg);

QDialogButtonBox *btn_box = new QDialogButtonBox(&dlg);
btn_box->setStandardButtons(QDialogButtonBox::Ok | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);

connect(btn_box, &QDialogButtonBox::accepted, &dlg, &QDialog::accept);
connect(btn_box, &QDialogButtonBox::rejected, &dlg, &QDialog::reject);

QFormLayout *layout = new QFormLayout();
layout->addRow(tr("Line edit 1:"), ledit1);
layout->addRow(tr("Line edit 2:"), ledit2);
layout->addWidget(btn_box);

dlg.setLayout(layout);

// В случае, если пользователь нажал "Ok".
if(dlg.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
    const QString &str1 = ledit1->text();
    const QString &str2 = ledit2->text();
}
```

Ключевой особенностью виджетной системы в Qt является использование т.н. менеджеров размещения - наследников класса `QLayout`. В примере эту роль берёт на себя `QFormLayout`. Именно он, ровно и с подписями, отстоящими с левой стороны, расположит два текстовых поля внутри диалога.

Comment: ИМХО, лучше использовать QtDesigner там где это возможно. Пока Ваш виджет ограничивается двумя полями ввода и двумя кнопками - это выглядит более-менее сносно, а когда там будет с десяток элементов на четыре вложенных layout - код разростется в ужас.

Comment: @Александр, не спорю. Это сугубо индивидуальное предпочтение. Я не люблю дизайнер, поскольку внутренний педант не приемлет ту грязь в коде, которая всенепременно возникает при генерации его машиной. Всё должно быть чётко, до последнего символа и отступа. Ну и в качестве контраргумента, все эти диалоги в основном стандартизированы и легко поддаются копи-пасте с небольшими изменениями, буде единожды написаны. Но, повторюсь, каждому своё.

Answer (score 0):

Пример, с одним edit и кнопками OK/Cancel -- диалог для ввода восьмеричного значения:
https://github.com/nzeemin/ukncbtl-qt/blob/master/qdialogs.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Вот элементарный пример такого диалога:
Создаем диалог, устанавливаем ему в lineEdit значения строк.
При нажатие кнопки Apply - строки из диалога сохраняем в переменные главной формы.

mydialog.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class MyDialog;
}

class MyDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyDialog();

    void setEdit1Text(const QString &_text);
    void setEdit2Text(const QString &_text);

    QString lineEdit1Text() const;
    QString lineEdit2Text() const;

private slots:
    void on_applyButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MyDialog *ui;
};
```

mydialog.cpp

```
#include "mydialog.h"
#include "ui_mydialog.h"

MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MyDialog::~MyDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MyDialog::setEdit1Text(const QString &_text)
{
    ui->lineEdit1->setText(_text);
}

void MyDialog::setEdit2Text(const QString &_text)
{
    ui->lineEdit2->setText(_text);
}

QString MyDialog::lineEdit1Text() const
{
    return ui->lineEdit1->text();
}

QString MyDialog::lineEdit2Text() const
{
    return ui->lineEdit2->text();
}

void MyDialog::on_applyButton_clicked()
{
    accept();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QString m_line1, m_line2;
};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "mydialog.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}



void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    MyDialog dialog;
    dialog.setEdit1Text(m_line1);
    dialog.setEdit2Text(m_line2);

    if(dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        m_line1 = dialog.lineEdit1Text();
        m_line2 = dialog.lineEdit2Text();
    }
}
```